# Managing size of personal geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, personal-geodatabase

I am currently running processing on two feature classes (points, number of points are 5000+ and 8000+ respectively) in ArcGIS 10.2 on personal geodatabase using iteration and selection by attributes/location.

The size of PGDB intially is only about 2MB however after the processing finishes it increases upto 400MB. My outputs of the processing are saved in a separate file GDB.

Can anyone explain to me why the size of original PGDB increases. Is this because the SQL queries are also saved in that PGDB.

How can I delete them? All i need is the original PGDB (with the orginal size) and the outputs stored in a separate GDB.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure at to the why, but how to address the issue, try running the [Compact](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000000n000000) tool on the mdb, that should trim some of the size.

Comment: The selections are stored internally to the database and that space is not reused, i.e. a new selection = more new space. All that unused space is dead rows in delta tables so a compact will get rid of it - that's what it's for. Consider using file geodatabase, it doesn't (seem to) have that problem.

Comment: File geodatabase also has a compaction option (a compression option as well, though they're [very different](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/File_geodatabases_compressing_vs_compacting/018s0000000r000000/)), but Access is much more profligate with disk space.

Comment: Personal Geodatabases are more prone to bloating @Vince, and it's very noticeable as it's all one file. File geodatabases are broken up into many files so it's not as immediately apparent if it is bloating - also file geodatabases don't have a 2GB size limit so aren't as affected by bloating either. I can recall a 2MB pGDB with a topology editing in ArcGis 8.3 maxing out and needing compacting twice a day (approx 1.8GB) then reducing back to 2MB. I had to keep an eye on the size and exit out when it got too big or 'save edits' would fail and I'd loose the edits.

Comment: I've always played with real databases (ORA,MSS,PG,DB2,INF), so I never had to sweat 2Gb limits, though loading 12Tb of raster catalogs without BIGFILE tablespaces was another story.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [compacting](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Compacting_file_and_personal_geodatabases/003n0000007t000000/) your personal geodatabase:

> as you delete and add records over time, the records within each file
>   lose their order, and unused space develops as records are removed and
>   new ones are added elsewhere in the file. This causes the file system
>   to perform more record-seeking operations within each file, slowing
>   the rate at which records are accessed.

To compact a geodatabase, right-click it in the Catalog tree and click Compact Database.

Comment: Like the quote, is there a link as to where it's from?

Comment: yeah, it's the link above ;)